# Calculations using multiple fields in SQL?

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

How would I calculate the highest goals per minute if I have a table that consists of fields for Goals and Minutes Played? At the moment I have it so the highest stat (whichever the user chooses) is put into a Label along with the forename and surname of the that particular record. I'd like to do the same thing but now using calculation which uses multiple fields. How would I do this? (Below is how I'm doing the bit I've already done)

```
ElseIf cb_Stat.Text = "Most Assists" Then
        SQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PlayerDatabase ORDER BY Assists DESC"
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Connection)
        da.Fill(ds, "PlayerDatabase")
        lbl_Result.Text = cb_Stat.Text & ": " & ds.Tables("PlayerDatabase").Rows(0).Item(2) & " " & ds.Tables("PlayerDatabase").Rows(0).Item(1) & " (" & ds.Tables("PlayerDatabase").Rows(0).Item(7) & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways of doing this:

```
select goals, minutes, round(goals/minutes,2) gpm --edit last digit for number of decimal places
from PlayerDB
order by goals/minutes
```

or this. It's a little bit longer, but cleaner, and can be incorporated into a view

```
select * from (
   select goals, minutes, round(goals/minutes,2) gpm --edit last digit for number of decimal places
   from PlayerDB
) order by gpm
```

Comment: `goals` and `minutes` are likely to be integers, thus resulting in an integer result for goals-per-minute. Could you adjust your answer to reliably give a floating-point value?

Comment: I was thinking of something more like `((goals * 1.0) / minutes) AS gpm` so that floating-point division is used instead of integer division ;)